# troubles with get_post_meta (and saving it)

Tags: post-meta, save-post

im having trouble using "add post meta" and "get post meta" : i have a new meta box in my taxonomy : i always have the value "empty meta" inside the input field, even after i enter anything : like 'banana' , i publish the article, and same thing : inside the field there is one more time "empty meta" ... (is it a problem with $post->id? i never really know if $post will be 'understood' depending how it is used)

```
/* Prints the box content */
    function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {
        // Use nonce for verification
        wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );
        $met = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ', true)? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ', true) : 'empty meta';

        /* input */
        echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
        _e("Description field : ", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
        echo '</label> ';
        echo '<input type="text" id="champ" name="champ" value="'.$met.'" />';
```

also, i tried to make the meta appear in my page, so i put :

```
<?php
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ_key', true) ) {
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "champ_key", true );
} else {
$meta = 'allo';
}
?>
```

but nothing appears on the page.

Do you know how i could go ahead with those post meta?

Thanks

**EDIT**

here's the complete code : if somebody could try it, i might doing something wrong, but i can't find out what. (the whole code is inside a widget page)

```
/*
 *
 * add meta box : habillage
 *
 */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'test1',
    __( 'My test1', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
    'post'
);
add_meta_box(
    'test2',
    __( 'My test2', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
    'movies'
);
}


/* Prints the box content */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {
global $post;
// Use nonce for verification
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );
$met = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ', true)? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ', true) : 'empty meta';

    /* input */
echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
_e("Description field : ", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="champ" name="champ" value="'.$met.'" />';




/* select list */
echo '<label for="my_list_field">';
_e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<select name="my_list_field" id="my_list_field">';

print_r ($post->ID);

global $post;

$s_query = new WP_Query( array(
'suppress_filters' => false,
'post_type' => 'movies'));
while($s_query->have_posts()):$s_query->the_post();

    $sname = $post->post_title;
    $s_output2 ='';
    $s_output2 .= '<option value="'.$post->ID.'" >';
    $s_output2 .= $post->post_title.' : allo';
    $s_output2 .= '</option>';
    echo $s_output2;

endwhile ;
echo '</select>';
wp_reset_query();
}


/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine.
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times
  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
  return;

  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
  //$mydata = $_POST['myplugin_new_field'];
  // Do something with $mydata
  // probably using add_post_meta(), update_post_meta()
  add_post_meta($post->ID, "champ_key", 'banana');

return $post_id;
//return $mydata;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the complete code : if somebody could try it, i might doing something wrong, but i can't find out what. (the whole code is inside a widget page)

```
/*
 *
 * add meta box : habillage
 *
 */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'test1',
    __( 'My test1', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
    'post'
);
add_meta_box(
    'test2',
    __( 'My test2', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
    'movies'
);
}


/* Prints the box content */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {
global $post;
// Use nonce for verification
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );
$met = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ', true)? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ', true) : 'empty meta';

    /* input */
echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
_e("Description field : ", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="champ" name="champ" value="'.$met.'" />';




/* select list */
echo '<label for="my_list_field">';
_e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<select name="my_list_field" id="my_list_field">';

print_r ($post->ID);

global $post;

$s_query = new WP_Query( array(
'suppress_filters' => false,
'post_type' => 'movies'));
while($s_query->have_posts()):$s_query->the_post();

    $sname = $post->post_title;
    $s_output2 ='';
    $s_output2 .= '<option value="'.$post->ID.'" >';
    $s_output2 .= $post->post_title.' : allo';
    $s_output2 .= '</option>';
    echo $s_output2;

endwhile ;
echo '</select>';
wp_reset_query();
}


/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine.
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
      return;

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times
  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
  return;

  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }
  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
  //$mydata = $_POST['myplugin_new_field'];
  // Do something with $mydata
  // probably using add_post_meta(), update_post_meta()
  add_post_meta($post->ID, "champ_key", 'banana');

return $post_id;
//return $mydata;
}
?>
```

Comment: try this: `add_post_meta($post_id, "champ", $_POST['champ'], true); update_post_meta($post_id, "champ", $_POST['champ']);`

Comment: @Michael : THANK YOU SO MUCH, it works perfect, thanks for your help Michael!

Comment: Note: clarifications of the original question should be *added to the original question*, as an edit, rather than posted as an "answer".

Comment: @Michael please move your solution to an answer to this can be cleaned up

Comment: copied the code suggestion from my comment into the answer section;

Answer (score 0):

try and add  `global $post;` direct inside your function.

edit: answer moved from comment to here:

try this code:

```
    add_post_meta($post_id, "champ", $_POST['champ'], true); 
update_post_meta($post_id, "champ", $_POST['champ']);
```

Comment: hi, no unfortunately, it's the same. Could you try it with my code? i put the code in the next post, (as "answer") this is what i put in a plugin "my_widget", if you can just have a look ...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a couple things are an issue here.

First, in your meta box callback (`myplugin_inner_custom_box`), you don't need to globalize post.  WordPress passes the post object as the first argument to that function.  So you'd change it a bit:

```
<?php
function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
// blah blah blah
}
```

The ternary statement to get your post meta is unnecessary.  get_post_meta returns an empty string if the given meta key isn't yet set.

```
$met = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'champ', true);
```

Now, in your saving function, you should probably use update_post_meta instead of add_post_meta.  As it's set now, add_post_meta will continue to add multiple meta values with the same key, which is probably not what you want.

Also, you're going to use `$post_id`, which you passed into your saving function in your new updated post meta called rather that $post->ID.

So...

```
<?php
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) 
        return;

    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )
    {
     if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page' ) )
     return;
    }
    else
    {
     if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) )
         return;
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['champ'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, "champ", $_POST['champ'] );
}
```

In your code above, you're saving the meta key with the name 'champ_key' then trying to retrieve it with the key 'champ'.  Can't do that!  Save and grab the post meta with the same key.

Your code, revised: http://pastie.org/2438831 (I took out the add_meta_box to movie call, and the select box, as I don't have a movie post type).